# How can I make journalctl use ccze by default?

Tags: debian, journalctl

I really like to colorize my `journalctl`-Output (tty) with `ccze` in Debian.

**Example:**

```
journalctl -b -k -f | ccze
```

How can I set `journalctl` to always pipe the output result through ccze without explicitly calling the pipe by `| ccze`?

Comment: A generic way would be to set a `journalctl()` shell function , but since [`journalctl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/journalctl.1.html) also supports `$PAGER`  and `$SYSTEMD_PAGER`  setting those in your profile or  an alias that sets `PAGER=ccze journalctl` or `SYSTEMD_PAGER=ccze journalctl` might also do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn, but I am not getting it!